# Ideas on flipping edit on Partner communities/Customer communities

Tags: apex, customer-community, partner-communities

We have built partner community and customer community(community cloud) which show data from the same set of objects. To avoid overwriting each other's changes, I am seeking help on ideas on the approach of allowing 'EDITS' on partner communities and customer communities exclusively.

We were thinking of having a Boolean field on the object which will be turned on/off to allow edits on partner/customer community respectively.

Further on this:

- On Partner community, edits can be handled by a validation rule(with the help of the mentioned Boolean flag and the login profile)
- On Customer community, the fields can be made un editable after reading the Boolean flag.

Since there is nothing OOTB available, this is what we got to.

Would highly appreciate if anyone has better ideas on this.

Comment: Are you saying that the platform's [Collision Detection](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328067&type=1&mode=1) feature does not address your concern?

Comment: Collision Detection kicks in on the Save after the edit. I was thinking of some way of locking the fields making them non editable when the same record is open for edit by another user.